# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAppPath' of undefined

Tags: node.js, electron, typeerror

We're using Electron `"electron": "^5.0.2"`

The code that is having the error is in the main process. It calls our backend services. I was trying to add a constant for the API path the same way we were including constants elsewhere (note: the solution here might be to use an environment variable). The issue is that electron is giving a error when it is trying to access the appPath() method. This same code works elsewhere in the app.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAppPath' of undefined`

```
const {app} = require('electron');

const path = require('path');
const constants = require(path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'src/constants'));
```

When the browser window is created we're setting nodeIntegration to true

```
  window = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}
  });
```

Comment: can you please add the folder structure for your repository?

Comment: Is this answer what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60444303/error-when-using-electron-app-getpathhome/60444989#60444989

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
const app = require('electron')

app.remote.app.getPath()
```

If that doesn't work you should try checking if `main.js` is:

- included in `package.json`
- NOT being required by your frontend JS or `index.html`
- of course, make sure electron is installed as a dev dependency
- if you are running into while trying to packaging the app you should run the code that uses `app` in a conditional, `app` isn't available while packaging but will be available in the prod

Answer (score 0):

In renderer.js:

```js
remote.app.getAppPath()
```