# Error when using electron `app.getPath('home');`

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have the following code within my `renderer.js` script I am using within my electron app:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
const {app} = require('electron');
$(document).ready(function() {
   let home = app.getPath('home');
   let homePathTemplate = document.getElementById('home');
   homePathTemplate.innerHTML(home);
});
```

Which looks as though it should work however receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined
```

Any ideas for a quick fix?

**Edit 1:**

With the following:

```
const app = require('electron');
```

And the same function as above I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: app.getPath is not a function at HTMLDocument.
```

Comment: Does `app` need to be destructured like that?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `{ app }` is called destructuring in JavaScript. It is basically pulling an export called 'app' out of that file. If it wasn't intentional on your part, try removing the curly braces.

Comment: Ok I tried what you said and have changed my questiob

Comment: @AlexHawking where is this code? Main or Renderer?

Comment: It is in renderer

Answer (score 3):

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
const { remote } = require('electron');
const app = remote.app;

$(document).ready(function() {
   let home = app.getPath('home');
   console.log(home)
   let homePathTemplate = document.getElementById('home');
   homePathTemplate.innerHTML(home);
});
```

And make sure you are enabling `nodeIntegration` when you are creating `BrowserWindow` in main process

Comment: is `nodeIntegration` needed for the app.getPath()` to work?

Comment: Upon where you need to use? If you wanna use in renderer, you need to enable `nodeIntegration`

Comment: I have `const app = require('electron');` defined in the *main.js* file and then want to use the `app` object again in my own script file that is called by the HTML listeners, but it seems like I cannot have produced 2 instances of the `app` object... is that right? If so, how can I access that `app` object in the other file? export it like in a module?

Comment: On the line `const app = remote.app;` it should also be destructured like `const { app } = remote;` Error thrown by linter.